# Maintain associations between objects and HTML elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

I am trying to build a page that will allow users to upload multiple files simultaneously, with separate progress bars for each file. (Similar to what Gmail does when you drag and drop multiple files into a new message.)

Here is a concise sample that deals with a single progress bar which works fine:

```
<div id="bar">
</div>
...
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
if (event.lengthComputable) {
    var percentage = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

    // update progress bar width
    document.getElementById("bar").style.width = percentage + "%";
  }
};
```

Note that I can easily access my progress bar because it is unique identifiable on the page and, therefore, accessible from within the event handler code.

Now suppose my JS code creates `XMLHttpRequest` objects and progress bars dynamically, i.e. one pair per each file that the user uploads. In that case each event handler needs to know which progress bar to update. But how can I maintain that association? All the event handler knows about is the event object, where `event.target` points to `req.upload` object (`XMLHttpUploadRequest`). I tried to maintain an array to map request object to progress bars, but could not make it work. Here is a simplified version:

```
var arr = Array();
....
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
  var newBar = addNewProgressBarToPage();
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var upload = req.upload;
  arr = arr.concat([{upload: newBar}]);

  upload.onprogress = function (event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
      var percentage = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

      // locate matching progress bar
      var bar = arr[event.target]; <--- returns undefined!
      ....
    }
  };
  ....
}
```

I suppose that object references cannot be used as array keys in JavaScript. I also suspect there is very simple way to address this problem, too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any reason for you to use or have to reference an array. I believe this may be what you want:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
  var newBar = addNewProgressBarToPage(); // What does this function do/return? A DOMElement?
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var upload = req.upload;

  upload.onprogress = function (event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
      var percentage = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

      // locate matching progress bar
      var bar = newBar; // This is your newBar from above. No need to reference an array.
      ....
    }
  };
  ....
}
```

If you did need that array for whatever reason, you would probably want to reference the array by the current value of `i` as set by the for loop. Additionally, if you only want to add a single value to an array, you should be using `push(item)` instead of `concat([item])`:

```
var arr = new Array(files.length); // Set the length of the array to the number of files we're uploading.
...
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
  arr[i] = addNewProgressBarToPage(); // We can assign values to the array's indices directly because we already set its size.
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var upload = req.upload;

  upload.onprogress = function (event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
      var percentage = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

      // locate matching progress bar
      var bar = arr[i];
      ....
    }
  };
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried similar solutions. In your first example, `var bar` would always point to the last created `newBar` value. (Yes, `addNewProgressBarToPage()` creates a new DOM element.)

Comment: Similarly, in your second example, `i` would reference an item outside of bounds of the array `arr` (i.e. `i == arr.length`, its last assigned value from the loop header.)